# Custom UI Binding objects to controls

Tags: c#

I am creating my own UI Binding system, which ties controls to their associated objects. What would be better than using a series of if-statements? If I add new controls to serve new track items, I would not want to update this series of if statements every time.

```
TimelineTrackControl control;
Type objectType = track.GetType();

if (objectType == typeof(ShotTrack))
{
    control = new ShotTrackControl();
}
else if (objectType == typeof(AudioTrack))
{
    control = new AudioTrackControl();
}
else if (objectType == typeof(GlobalItemTrack))
{
    control = new GlobalItemTrackControl();
}
else
{
    control = new TimelineTrackControl();
}

control.TargetTrack = track;
timelineTrackMap.Add(track, control);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Create a `Dictionary<Type, Type>` that contains the track types and the corresponding control types:

   ```
   private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> ControlTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
   {
       { typeof(ShotTrack), typeof(ShotTrackControl) },
       ...
   };
   ```

   To get a corresponding control:

   ```
   control = Activator.CreateInstance(ControlTypes[track.GetType()]);
   ```
2. Create a `Dictionary<Type, Func<Control>>` that contains the track types and the corresponding control creators:

   ```
   private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<Control>> ControlTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Control>>
   {
       { typeof(ShotTrack), () => new ShotTrackControl() },
       ...
   };
   ```

   To create a new corresponding control:

   ```
   control = ControlTypes[track.GetType()]();
   ```
3. Define a custom attribute that stores the corresponding control type:

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
   public class TrackControlAttribute : Attribute
   {
       public readonly Type ControlType;

       public TrackControlAttribute(Type controlType)
       {
           ControlType = controlType;
       }
   }

   [TrackControl(typeof(ShotTrackControl))]
   public class ShotTrack
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

   To create a new corresponding control:

   ```
   object[] attrs = track.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TrackControlAttribute), true);
   if (attrs.Length != 0);
       control = Activator.CreateInstance(((TrackControlAttribute)attrs[0]).ControlType);
   ```

   **EDIT**
   Bug fixed in the 3rd option.

Comment: I really like option #3. Though I think I will make the Attribute for the control and point to it's track. That way the tracks have no knowledge of the controls.

Comment: Oops. I made a mistake in the getting of the attribute. I updated the sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection, in this case http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d133hta4 like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(null, track.GetType().toString() + "Control");
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but will only really work if you keep your class names consistent.